# Extension Class only one method is accessible

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have this StringExtensions class

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string LeftOf(string input, string delimiter, StringComparison sc = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        int index = input.IndexOf(delimiter, sc);
        if (index >= 0) return input.Substring(0, index);
        else
            return input; // Delimiter not found, return the whole input string
    }
    public static string RightOf(string input, string delimiter, StringComparison sc = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        int index = input.IndexOf(delimiter, sc);
        if (index >= 0) return input.Substring(index + delimiter.Length);
        else
            return string.Empty; // Delimiter not found, return an empty string
    }
    public static string RemoveBetweenTags(this string input, string startTag, string endTag, out string content)
    {
        content = null;
        string pattern = $"{Regex.Escape(startTag)}(.*?){Regex.Escape(endTag)}";
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        if (match.Success) content = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
        return result;

    }
}
```

only the method RemoveBetweenTags is accessible.
Why not the other two methods are not accessible ?

Comment: You’re missing the `this` keyword in front of the first (`string`) parameter for the other two methods.

Comment: you missed 'this' in the declaraion of the other 2

Answer (score 1):

You need the `this` keyword on each extension method.

Also, may I recommend to combine the `LeftOf()` and `RightOf()` methods into one so that you only need to do one `.IndexOf()` call which is expensive. Use an `out` parameter to return the remaining text to the right of the delimiter.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"aaa__bbb";

        string left = input.UpTo("__", out var right);

        Console.WriteLine(left);    // "aaa"
        Console.WriteLine(right);   // "bbb"
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string UpTo(this string input, string delimiter, out string remainder,  StringComparison sc = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        int index = input.IndexOf(delimiter, sc);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            remainder = input.Substring(index + delimiter.Length);
            return input.Substring(0, index);
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = string.Empty;
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```